# Strange interaction between Alpha and legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

While plotting several ecdf curves that overlapped, I tried adjusting the alpha of the curves to improve visibility. While tinkering with the correct placement of alpha, I found the following.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(Var = rep(1:3, 10000)) %>%
  mutate(Val = rnorm(10000)*Var,
         Var = factor(Var)) %>%
  arrange(Var, Val) %>%
  group_by(Var) %>%
  mutate(ecdf = ecdf(Val)(Val))

ggplot(x, aes(x=Val)) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(color = Var), size = 1.25, alpha = .9)
```

This gives the lines the correct alpha, but makes the legend useless. (I'm only using alpha=.9 here to demonstrate the point that the legend colors completely disappear). The work around I've found is to add:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=Val)) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(color = Var), size = 1.35, alpha = .9) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes= list(alpha = 1)))
```

So while I have a solution for my immediate problem, can someone explain why the first call to ggplot is messed up? Is this a bug? If it makes any difference, I believe this issue also exists when using geom_line (though a slightly different data.frame is needed).

Wierd. Here's my sessionInfo(). I've also checked to see if there are any outdated packages.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932  LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932  LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 ggplot2_1.0.1      stringr_1.0.0      tidyr_0.2.0        dplyr_0.4.2       
[6] data.table_1.9.4  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.11.6      magrittr_1.5     MASS_7.3-40      munsell_0.4.2    colorspace_1.2-6
[6] R6_2.0.1         plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.1      parallel_3.2.1   grid_3.2.1      
[11] gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        lazyeval_0.1.10  assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.8    
[16] reshape2_1.4.1   labeling_0.3     stringi_0.5-4    scales_0.2.5     chron_2.3-47    
[21] proto_0.3-10
```

Comment: So it would seem that this is only an issue in the RStudio Viewing pane. As I was copying my plot to paste in here, the legend shows up correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are they different? What am I missing?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)

x <- data.frame(Var = rep(1:3, 10000)) %>%
  mutate(Val = rnorm(10000)*Var,
         Var = factor(Var)) %>%
  arrange(Var, Val) %>%
  group_by(Var) %>%
  mutate(ecdf = ecdf(Val)(Val))

ggplot(x, aes(x=Val)) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(color = Var), size = 1.25, alpha = .9) -> gg1

ggplot(x, aes(x=Val)) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(color = Var), size = 1.35, alpha = .9) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes= list(alpha = 1))) -> gg2

grid.arrange(gg1, gg2)
```

[image]